# SQL Server: Select Where String Doesn't Contain Certain Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to Select the employees from Department10 where the name does not contain the string "LA".

```
Select *
From EMP
Where Cod_Dept = 10
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Select *
From EMP
Where Cod_Dept = 10 
And Name Not Like '%LA%'
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using `CHARINDEX()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE Cod_Dept = 10
AND CHARINDEX('LA' , Name , 0) = 0;
```

In case you have `Null` value and you want to return it too:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP
WHERE Cod_Dept = 10
AND (CHARINDEX('LA' , Name , 0) = 0) OR (CHARINDEX('LA' , Name , 0) Is Null);
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/MZSZD32848).**

Comment: Seems to be a never ending debate charindex vs like.   I prefer charindex  for wildcard searches for two reasons 1) easier to pass a variable without having to concatinate a string with %, and 2) more important ... performance.   http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/like-vs-substring-vs-leftright-vs-charindex  anyway +1

Comment: `LIKE` is sargable if no leading wildcard so can easily beat `CHARINDEX` in that case. Presumably something not tested in that link from a quick glance at the results. With `CHARINDEX` you don't have to worry about escaping characters like `%`.  Cardinality estimation can be different between the two.

Comment: Why `<1` rather than `=0`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Agreed... with no leading wildcards LIKE is the way to go.  That said, my tests of LIKE vs CHARINDEX were not as dramatic as the results in the link, there was a notable differance favoring CHARINDEX

Comment: + `Cod_Dept = 10 AND Name NOT LIKE '%LA%'` won't return the rows where `Name IS NULL` @MartinSmith